# How to load unity settings from config file?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have an *unity* configuration file(`App.config`) as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Unity.Configuration"/>
  </configSections>
  <unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <alias alias="IProductService" type="UnityExample.Service.IProductService, UnityExample.Service" />
    <containers>
      <container name="Service">
        <register type="IProductService" mapTo="ProductService"/>
      </container>
    </containers>
  </unity>
</configuration>
```

Now I want to *load* the configuration from above `file`.

```
var container = new UnityContainer().LoadConfiguration("Service");
```

But I received following error:

> [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: section]
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityContainerExtensions.LoadConfiguration(IUnityContainer
>   container, UnityConfigurationSection section, String containerName)

Comment: Do you really need to use the configuration file to configure the dependencies? I find it easier to create a Boostrapper class and register the dependencies there - here's an example (ignore the DependencyResolver line, it's used in ASP.NET MVC applications): https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/implement-ioc-using-unity-in-mvc-5/

Comment: @RuiJarimba, yes, I need to use the configuration file in order to load assemblies dynamically.

Comment: Which version of Unity and .NET Framework are you using?

Comment: @RuiJarimba, .NET 4.6.1 and Unity 5.8.6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to make it work. I have created a demo console application using the same namespaces you're using, as follows:

[image: Assembly information]

Nuget packages installed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Unity" version="5.8.6" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Unity.Abstractions" version="3.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Unity.Configuration" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

App.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Unity.Configuration"/>
    </configSections>

    <unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
        <assembly name="UnityExample" />
        <namespace name="UnityExample.Service" />

        <containers>
            <container name="Service">
                <register type="IProductService" mapTo="ProductService"/>
            </container>
        </containers>
    </unity>

    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Unity.Configuration" publicKeyToken="6d32ff45e0ccc69f" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Code:

```
namespace UnityExample.Service
{
    public interface IProductService
    {

    }

    public class ProductService : IProductService
    {
    }
}
```

Main:

```
using System.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration;

using Unity;
using UnityExample.Service;

namespace UnityExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            UnityConfigurationSection section = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");
            section.Configure(container, "Service");

            IProductService service = container.Resolve<IProductService>();
        }
    }
}
```