# How can we resolve dependency with configuration file settings

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I am kind of new to the dependency injection resolver techniques topic. May I know how we can resolve dependency through configuration file section(s)? Below are my classes and interface along with the config file.

I am sure that missing some portion of code/setting. Can you please help me with this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UnityConfiguration_Testing
{
    public interface IUserAuthentication
    {
        string Authenticate(string username, string password);
        string GetUserRole(string username);
    }
}

public class CloudAppAuthetication: IUserAuthentication
{
    public string Authenticate(string username, string password)
    {
        return "This Authenticate method executed from cloud class";//Jwt token based authentication logic should be there
    }

    public string GetUserRole(string username)
    {
        return "This GetUserRole method executed from cloud class";//New logic to user management api call
    }
}

public class StandaloneAppAuthetication : IUserAuthentication
{
      public string Authenticate(string username, string password)
      {
          return "This Authenticate method executed from standalone class";//current logic should be here
      }

      public string GetUserRole(string username)
      {
           return "This GetUserRole method executed from standalone class";//current logic should be here
      }
  }
```

Console application calling of interface method:

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UnityConfiguration_Testing
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
            container.LoadConfiguration("TestContainer");
            IUserAuthentication _userAuthentication = null;
            string validatedUser = _userAuthentication.Authenticate("testuser@user.com", "testpassword");
            string validatedUserRole = _userAuthentication.GetUserRole("testuser@user.com");
        }
    }
}
```

My App.config file of console application is:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <configSections>
       <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration" />
    </configSections>
    <unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
      <container name="TestContainer">
        <register type="UnityConfiguration_Testing.IUserAuthentication,UnityConfiguration_Testing" mapTo="UnityConfiguration_Testing.StandaloneAppAuthetication,UnityConfiguration_Testing" />
      </container>
    </unity>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
```

Comment: Did you evaluated Factory pattern? Or else if you are using DI, you may evaluate a case where you change the DI registration based on the web.config entry?

Answer (score 0):

Inversion Of Control contener is what you want to have. 
There are many. For example Autofac. They have ability to register implementations for interface depending on your configuration in config files or you can configure it at runtime.

Comment: Sorry Adam. I really not sure why I clicked down vote for your answer. Actually it is the right approach. And worked well.

Just for all other sake, the solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51399322/how-to-load-unity-settings-from-config-file

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, this is roughly what you're looking for.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Type t = Type.GetType("Second"); //get class name from config here
         MethodInfo method 
             = t.GetMethod("Hello", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public); // get method by name here

        Console.WriteLine(method.Invoke(null,null));
    }
}

public static class First
{
    public static string Hello(){
    return "hello"; 
    }
}
public static class Second 
{
    public static string Hello(){
    return "Hello World";   
    }
}
```

This will allow you to get a class and method defined by names you can get from the config file.